# При написании формулы в библиотеке openpyxl, excel выдает ошибку связанную с прочтением формулы

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Среда - jupyter notebook

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\Dell\....xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
ws['D1'].value = '=СУММ(B1;B2;B3;B4)'
wb.save(r'C:\Users\Dell\....xlsx')
```

Ошибка : [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DutZj.png]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Попробуйте поменять разделители (точка с запятой) на запятую. А еще лучше записать диапазоном: `=СУММ(B1:B4)`

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогла тема с изменением разделителя

Comment: Диапазоном лучше - нет зависимости от локализации